# Boost.Python Multiple Return Arguments

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a C++ function that returns multiple values from its arguments.

```
void Do_Something( double input1, double input2, double input3,
    double& output1, double& output2 )
{
    ...
    output1 = something;
    output2 = something;
}
```

I want to wrap this function using Boost.Python.  I've come up with a solution using lambdas, but its sort of tedious since I have many functions that have multiple return values in their arguments.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( mymodule )
{
    using boost::python;
    def( "Do_Something", +[]( double input1, double input2, double input3 )
    {
        double output1;
        double output2;
        Do_Something( input1, input2, input3, output1, output2 );
        return make_tuple( output1, output2 );
    });
}
```

Is there a better\automatic way to do accomplish this with Boost.Python?

Comment: Unfortunately I think there is not better option. The only thing I can think to help you in the tedious process is using ``cog`` to generate the functions automatically for you (considering that the functions follows the same "template").

Answer (score 6):

An improvement could be:

```
boost::python::tuple Do_Something(double input1, double input2,
                                  double input3) {
    // Do something
    ...
    return boost::python::make_tuple(output1, output2);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule) {
    def("Do_Something", Do_Something);
}
```

Comment: Please complement your question explaining where the improvement is.